# MongodDB Java driver v3 - how to create cursor with projection?

Tags: mongodb-java

The following works with mongodb java driver v2. How do I achieve the same result with new drivers of v3 using new set of classes like MongoCollection, etc:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilder.start().and(...);
DBObject projection = new BasicDBObject();
projection.put("_id", 1);
projection.put("h", 1);

DBCursor cursor = new DBCursor(collection, query.get(), projection);
while(cursor.hasNext()){
   DBObject dbo = cursor.next();
   String h = dbo.get("h").toString();
   ...
}
```

I particularly want to use projection and iterate over large result set. Also, if there is good reference guide about how to migrate from v2 to v3, I'd be very grateful. So far lost in documentations..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you really shouldn't be creating a `DBCursor` yourself.  You should be getting them via `DBCollection`.  As for the new API version, it'd look something like this:

`collection.find(query).projection(new Document(...)))`

For more info, see [this](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/builders/projections/) page.